# Georeference image is mirrored

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

[image]

I'm working with QGIS and I'm trying to geo-reference a tobin lease map.  The map datum: NAD27, projection: UTM Zone 14N.  The process to georeference is fairly straight forward but the results I'm getting is off.  The program is basically mirroring the image. I have tried it three times with the same results.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I've seen this too in the past, and would like to hear an answer. If I recall correctly though, it had to do with the CRS not being set properly. Can you confirm that your map CRS is properly set?

Comment: it appears to be right.  Nad27/ UTM zone 14N.  The CRS code in QGIS is EPSG:26714

Comment: can you post an image showing the gcp table?

Comment: there is a screen shot of the table.  I have tried with more points and it still have not worked.

Answer (score 4):

Located in the USA, you have to put the x values (West) negative (as East) when they are given in degrees.

Looking at your screenshot, I think you missed that step.

Comment: To explain further, X is the longitude. If you're putting in positive longitudes, you're moving the object to central Europe, but also reversing the "direction" of longitude.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for the info.  I had thought of that earlier and tried to manual add the negative in the table.  I guess it did not effect the CRS.  I didn't know if the program would automatically add the negative based on the CRS.  I guess not. Thanks again guys.  This will save me a lot of time.